# Multiplayer game with PHP. What are my chances?

Tags: php, comet

Firstly, I would need this information to make a realtime multiplayer browser game. Right now, I can pretty much code everything, with an exception - serverside events has to be pushed to clients. So I need a real solution (unlike longpolling) on this.

I've been reading all the forums, all the articles, but this is confusing me.

I would like to ask some questions, but I need an indepth reply, if possible.

1. HTML5 brought us the WebSockets feature. It was barely supported by browsers at first, but right now, pretty much all up-to-date browsers supports it. Is it going to be the comet solution of future? Can it kill node.js and other solutions?
2. There are so many options to pick from. Node.js, socket.io, APE, using API's of 3rd party websites. (like pusher.com) What would be the most benefical for me? I want to code server-side with PHP. I believe if we use node.js, I should code server-side with javascript too. Is it correct? If not, how can I use PHP with these frameworks?
3. I am going to code a multiplayer game, so performance/scalability is an essential. I don't think I will ever get more than 100 concurrent players at the start, but nobody knows what future brings, so I would like it to code the way it can support few thousands of concurrent players in the future. What are my options?
4. PHP, as much as I like the language itself, it simply lacks in this area... I don't want to code games like Travian, they're boring. I would like them to be realtime. I can learn a new language for this task if necessary. What's your opinions about this?
5. I'm currently using Apache as a local web server. Used IIS and Nginx in the past. Is there any PHP web servers designed for this job? As far as I know, some languages had special web servers designed for concurrency. (e.g Tornado Web)

Setting max_execution_time to 0 and flushing new data to clients in an endless loop is not an option in this case, it is not even effective at all.

Any answer is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Ps. I will use it for other things like realtime notifications too, but mostly my 2D game itself.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to check out `socket.io` project.

Comment: This q will almost certainly be closed as too broad - especially since it is five questions in one. I suspect ultimately it would be better for you to do some solid research and then return with specific technology/code questions `:)`

Comment: FWIW, my suspicion is that you are in danger of losing yourself in unnecessary detail and premature optimisation. I would recommend building the absolute minimum working system, as quickly as you can, even if it is slow and clunky. Use language you know best, as learning Node (or whatever) will slow your dev down to a crawl whilst you try to learn it in parallel. Then optimise/improve/rewrite from there, based on real user feedback.

Comment: Also: _I don't want to code games like Travian, they're boring_. I agree you should code on things that interest you, but equally you need to be led by what people will **play**. Don't build something _just_ because you like it - check other people will like it too!

Comment: Halfer, I appreciate your replies but I didn't want to ask my questions seperatedly. While I understand your point, I don't want to change my codes entirely to support few thousand people in the future. I don't want to save the day, so I would like to learn how it is being done in the most professional way. Yeah, games like Travian has a huge playerbase, but they're not realtime games. My game is going to be 2D hack & slash (like how Arcuz is on flash) so interact with players is an essential. :)

Comment: Afshin, I already checked socket.io and countless of other options. I just can't compare them.

Comment: I'm not a game dev, but I do have a good number of years of programming experience. It's up to you whether you take my advice, of course, but many a side-project ceases work because development is too slow (due to an unfamiliar language, or due to too many questions being considered too early). I partly agree with @afuzzyllama - PHP is unsuitable on the client side, for which you'll need either JS or (maybe) Flash. It may not be _ideal_ on the server, but if you choose Node (etc) you may get 'stuck in the mud' and not ever get to alpha. That all said, best of luck with it.

Comment: The most important feature in `socket.io` is that support many of browsers and old IE(s) also, even IE 5.5!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not designed for this.  I suggest you pick a language that is designed for this type of application.

To answer your questions:

1. The idea of web sockets is to write a game client that can interface with a game server.  If you are looking to build a game that uses sockets, PHP will not fit this mold.  You need something that will run continuously and most likely be multi-threaded.  You are looking at C#, C++, Java, etc.  It will not will node.js because node.js is a server.  In a browser you are writing a client.
2. I'm not sure how to respond to this because node.js != PHP.  node.js is designed to be a web server.  This means that the server takes web requests and sends back the proper response (think like Apache's HTTPD).  PHP is a scripting language that interfaces with apache to be able to do more dynamic html processing.
3. Use C++, Java, C#, etc
4. Learn C++, Java, C#, or any other language that supports sockets.
5. No, a web server is suppose to accept a request, process it, and return the result.  If you are looking for continuous communication between a client and a server, a web server is not what you are looking for.

There are products out there that already take care of a lot of the ground work.  I recommend you look at something like [Photon](http://photon.exitgames.com/) or [Smart Fox Server](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/)